# Creating an email that can trigger a script

Tags: bash, email

I have a CentOS 6.3 server. I would like to create an email address like, for example, list@myserver.com that will be a special kind of email that will trigger a script.

For example: suppose I mail list@myserver.com and the subject is an IP address. I want the server to receive that mail, extract that IP from the subject and append it to a file.

How is this done on Linux? Can you guys tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things involved with doing this:

1. How to get the email to the system
2. process the email to append info to a file

The first you can solve by having the mail be sent to the server directly, but if the server is not online all the time (located at home), it is probably better to have the emails sent to some Google or Yahoo account and fetch them from there.
You can do that with [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/), and have the mail delivered locally to a user `list`.

For the second part you can use [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/), with specific rules for the user in `~/.procmailrc`. The local mail delivery agent needs to be told to use `procmail` e.g. in `postfix` you add:

```
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

to your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file.

In the file `~list/.procmailrc` you can specify rules on what to do with mail (all mails arriving there, or the ones with specific characteristics (subject, from address, etc)). `procmail` has several useful build in actions, and if those do not suffice you can pipe the mail into a program to do something specific it cannot do.

Comment: very good!!!! Thanks I will research that!

Answer (score 2):

You need a server that handles incoming mail, and a client which interprets that mail.

As a start:

1. Install [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) or a similar MTA;
2. Configure it to handle any mail it receives to its hostname locally;
3. Either add a Postfix hook, or use something like [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to wait for new mail and run your script on its arrival.